# NHibernate - Schema Export

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Nowaday I am using NHibernate + ASP.NET MVC 3 in my project. Always I add a new class model I need to set the SchemaExport like this:

```
Fluently
       .Configure()
       .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(connectionString).ShowSql())
       .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
           .AddFromAssembly(typeof(Usuario).Assembly)
           .AddFromAssembly(typeof(Empresa).Assembly)
           .AddFromAssembly(typeof(TipoUsuario).Assembly))

       .ExposeConfiguration(config =>
       {
           var schemaExport = new SchemaExport(config);
           schemaExport.Drop(true, true);
           schemaExport.Create(true, true);
       })
```

Is there any way to everytime the schemaExport export a new model insert a collection of default values in a couples of tables?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not strictly answering your question, I've found that using NHibernate to generate the schema quickly hits the types of problems you are currently facing. So, instead of using NHibernate I use [Fluent Migrator](http://www.github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator) instead. You can then create / modify your schema and add data into the schema in a very nice fluent based API without tying yourself to a specific flavour of SQL.